# Multiple Google Analytics codes for individual pages

Tags: google-analytics

I've seen a couple of posts on here with the same subject but none matching what I'd like to do.

My site has a Google Analytics code for the whole main site - say `www.example.com`

There are 2 pages on the site that Id like to individually monitor and I have a GA code for each page - let's say `/page1` and `/page1/page2`

Is it possible in Wordpress for GA to monitor:

- GA code 1 - whole website but exclude `/page1` and `/page2`
- GA code 2 - just the page at `www.example.com/page1`
- GA code 3 - just the page at `www.example.com/page1/page2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, that's possible. Are you including the GA-code anywhere on your site today? If not, you can add the following code to your theme's functions.php-file:

```
add_action('wp_head', 'add_google_analytics');

function add_google_analytics(){
    global $post; 

    if (is_page('page1')){ ?>
        <!-- Analytics code #1 -->
    <?php } else if (is_page('page2')) { ?>
        <!-- Analytics code #2 -->
    <?php } else { ?>
        <!-- Analytics code #3 -->
    <?php }
 }
```

Comment: I currently have my main sites GA code inserted using a Google Analytics plugin. But its no issue to delete that plugin so it takes it out. Ill give it a blast now. Thanks

Comment: Are there errors in this code? Moaning about an unexpected "else if"? Im trying to create it into a plugin as per this link here: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/create-google-analytics-plugin/?wpcv=b&utm_expid=3606929-92.rprqzZQVQVO9C0D8ZR2AsQ.1&utm_referrer=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.co.uk%2F

Comment: @nginxnovice Shoot, sorry, forgot to add end curly braces before the `else if` and `else`. Try the updated code!

Comment: Thanks Emil, ill try it now. Do i post in the whole GA code snippet or just the actual   ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-xx', 'auto');
  ga('send', 'pageview'); bit?

Comment: Up to you - in this snippet you paste the whole code block in each condition :)

Comment: Ive made it into a plugin rather than adding it to the function.php file so it wont get overwritten with theme upgrades. And it works a treat woth your code. Thankyou Emil, very much appreciated. Merry Christmas :-)

Comment: Good idea :) Merry christmas, indeed! If my answer was helpful, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to it :) ✔︎